# How can you connect to iTunes library in your program. What api or classes are used in this

Tags: ios, itunes

How can you connect to an iTunes library in your iPhone program?  What API or classes are used in this?  I need to make an app similar to the REMOTE app that exists: to be able to connect to an iTunes library on someones computer and see their list of songs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. The remote API has been reverse-engineered for the Android iTunes remote at http://dacp.jsharkey.org/ but I don't believe for a second that Apple would allow such an app on the App Store.

Accessing the music stored in a remote iTunes library is not directly possible (without installing additional software alongside iTunes). [DAAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol), the protocol used by iTunes to share music, has not yet been successfully reverse-engineered, and if you managed it, not only would Apple reject your app, they'd probably ban you and maybe sue you.

Your best bet would probably be to write a server app that runs alongside iTunes.